# Generalization of sum of outer product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, matrix-rank

Consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times m}$ such that $m \geq d$ and  denote its columns i.e $A_{:, i}$ by $a_i$. Let $AA^T$ is invertible.

Now, consider the sum $S(A) = \sum_{r=1}^m  a_r a^T_r$ which is an $d \times d$ matrix.

Note that each $a_r a_r^T$ is a rank 1 matrix. 
Note that when m = d, it follows from [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2406283/sum-of-the-outer-products-of-n-independent-vectors-is-always-full-rank).

Is rank(S(A)) = d ?

Example: A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

S(A) = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}

S in this example is full rank.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  It seems to me that $S(A) = AA^T$.  So, if $AA^T$ is invertible, of course $S(A)$ is invertible since it is the same matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I did not see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Omnomnomnom pointed out: Looks like $S(A) = AA^T$.

Comment: Since the answer is from OP himself/herself, I think it's a valid answer.